# is there a way of showing documents after a sum aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl, elasticsearch-5

I've been trying lately to retrieve information about sales on Kibana DSL.
I've been told to show vendors information PLUS their monthly sales.
(I'll use the "Kibana_sample_data_ecommerce" for this example)

I already did this aggregation in order to group all clients by their 'customer_id':

```
#Aggregations (group by)
GET kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "size": 0,  
    "aggs": {
      "by user_id": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "customer_id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "add_field_to_bucket": {
              "top_hits": {"size": 1, "_source": {"includes": ["customer_full_name"]}}
            }
          }
      }
    }
 }
```

in which i've included customer_full_name in the result:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "by user_id" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 2970,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "27",
          "doc_count" : 348,
          "add_field_to_bucket" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : 348,
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "kibana_sample_data_ecommerce",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "fhwUR3sBpfDKGuVlpu8r",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "customer_full_name" : "Elyssa Underwood"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

So, in this result i know that 'Elyssa Underwood' with 'customerid' '27' has 348 hits (or documents related).
Also i recquire to know the total spent by 'Elyssa' on those products, using the field 'products.taxful_price'.
The thing is that i cannot perform a subaggregation on top_hits (as far as i know); Also I've tried to do a sum_aggregation, but it ends on the same result (i got my sum, but i cannot access top_hits sub aggregation at that point).

At the end of the day i want to have a result like this:

```
 "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "kibana_sample_data_ecommerce",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "fhwUR3sBpfDKGuVlpu8r",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "customer_full_name" : "Elyssa Underwood",
                    "total_spent": 1234.5678 
                  }
                }
              ]
```

Is there something I can do to achieve it?.

PS: I'm using ElasticSearch 5.x and also I have access to NEST client, if there's a solution I can reach through it.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: fwiw Elasticsearch 5.X has been EOL for a number of years, you should really upgrade :)

Comment: I know, but this is the environment that is installed on the new company i'm working on. And i've trying to come with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below as sample data.

Data:

```
{
  "customer_id":2,
  "client-name":"b",
  "purchase": 2001
}
```

Query:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "customer_id",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_sales": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "purchase"
          }
        },
        "documents":{
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Result:

```
{
          "key" : 2,
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "documents" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 1,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index1",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "0HPzcHsBjw4ziwrzGzrq",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "customer_id" : 2,
                    "client-name" : "b",
                    "purchase" : 2001
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "total_sales" : {
            "value" : 2001.0
          }
        }
```